# Group data by ABAB pattern along a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to decrease the size of my pandas dataframe by looking for any 'ABAB' patterns that I would simplify by 'AB' and summing the count.

Example:

```
 df=pd.DataFrame()
 df['letter'] = ['a','b','c','b','c', 'a', 'c', 'b']
 df['count'] = [1, 6, 7 , 2 , 7, 1 , 3, 3 ] 
 print(df)
```

We see the pattern I mentioned for the 'letter' column: 'bcbc'. I dont want to group the 'cac' for example.
So I want to sum the count for each of the letter within the pattern
summing the count for the 'b' and the 'c' each. In this example
the output should be then:

```
df['letter']= ['a','b','c', 'a', 'c', 'b']
df['count'] = [1, 8, 14 , 1 , 3, 3 ]
```

Comment: what if there was a row with d in between the two bc/bc? same output?

Comment: No, I only want to reduce consecutive patterns BCBC --> BC 
but BCDBC would stay like this

Comment: What is the priority in case of `b c b c b`? How do you reduce `b c b c b c`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, how do you work with `a b a b c b c`?